# How to compare consecutive rows and add a column based on the condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas-groupby

I am trying to calculate the difference between two consecutive rows in pandas dataframe and based on the result I want to populate a column with some value.

For example:

Below is a sample data

```
ID Date
1   2/2/2018
2   2/3/2018
3   2/18/2018
3   2/19/2018
3   2/27/2018
4   5/5/2018
4   6/9/2018
5   6/10/2018
6   7/1/2018
6   7/2/2018
6   7/10/2018
6   7/30/2018
6   8/1/2018
6   8/3/2018
7   8/10/2018
```

The data is grouped by ID.

Below is the sample output data

[image]

So, whenever the ID is changing the column "Code" has "I". For same ID if the difference between two consecutive dates is less than 30 then column "Code" has "R1" and for the same ID if the next date is within 30 days of the previous one "Code" will have "R2" and for the same ID if the next data is within 30 days of the previous one "Code" will have "R4". For example take case ID--"4" both the rows of "Code" is "I" because even though ID = 4, the two dates are more than 30 days apart from each other. 6/9/2018 - 5/5/2018 = 34.

```
sorted_data["Code"] = "I"
def conditions(data):
    if data['Completed Date'].diff() <=30:
        val = "R1"
    elif  data['Completed Date'].diff() <=30:
        val = "R2"
    elif  data['Completed Date'].diff() <=30:
        val = "R3"
    elif data['Completed Date'].diff() <=30:
        val = "R4"
    elif data['Completed Date'].diff() <=30:
        val = "R5"
    elif data['Completed Date'].diff() <=30:
        val = "R6"
    elif data['Completed Date'].diff() <=30:
        val = "R7"
    elif data['Completed Date'].diff() <=30:
        val = "R8"
    return val
for groups, data in sorted_data.groupby("Cust_No"):
    print(conditions(sorted_data))
```

I don't know how to pick up the next row value to compare the dates. The code above is not working and giving me error.

Comment: Look into using [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html)

Comment: @Deya, please post text that can be copied to create sample datasets, images are no good.

Comment: @HaleemurAli, I reformatted it. Let me know if you anymore information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably not optimal, but on way would be to use iterrows:

```
prev_id = 'x' 
prev_date = pd.to_datetime('1/1/1900')
prev_rpt = 0
for idx,ser in df.iterrows():
    if ser.ID == prev_id and (ser.Date - prev_date).days < 30:
        prev_rpt += 1
        df.loc[idx,'Code'] = 'R' + str(prev_rpt)
    else:
        df.loc[idx,'Code'] = 'I'
        prev_rpt = 0
    prev_id = ser.ID
    prev_date = ser.Date
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.

Answer (score 3):

Group by `ID` and find all rows where the date difference from the prior date is less than or equals 30.

Then group by `ID` again, get the cumulative sum and set `I` where the value equals 0 else prefix with `R`

```
x = df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda x: x.Date-x.Date.shift() <= pd.Timedelta(days=30)).astype(int) 
df['out'] = x.groupby('ID').cumsum().apply(lambda x: 'I' if x == 0 else f'R{x}').reset_index(drop=True)  

# output:

    ID       Date out
0    1 2018-02-02   I
1    2 2018-02-03   I
2    3 2018-02-18   I
3    3 2018-02-19  R1
4    3 2018-02-27  R2
5    4 2018-05-05   I
6    4 2018-06-09   I
7    5 2018-06-10   I
8    6 2018-07-01   I
9    6 2018-07-02  R1
10   6 2018-07-10  R2
11   6 2018-07-30  R3
12   6 2018-08-01  R4
13   6 2018-08-03  R5
14   7 2018-08-10   I
```